# Using WebKit in SwiftUI hides keyboard when view updates

Tags: keyboard, webkit, swiftui, wkwebview, uikeyboard

I've created a minimum reproducible example of this problem I'm facing.

First, I created a `WKWebView` housed in a `UIViewRepresentable` to be used with SwiftUI. Then, I set up a `WKUserContentController` and a `WKWebViewConfiguration` so the `WKWebView` can send messages to native code. In this case, I have a `<textarea>` that sends over its `value` on input.

The value sent over through WebKit is assigned to a `@State` variable which causes the view to update. Unfortunately, the `WKWebView` is deselected whenever the view updates. How can I work around this? The `WKWebView` needs to stay selected until the user deliberately chooses to hide the keyboard.

This is a minimal example of what's happening:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let html: String
    let configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        .init(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    final class Coordinator: NSObject, WKScriptMessageHandler {
        @Binding var text: String

        init(text: Binding<String>) {
            _text = text
        }

        func userContentController(
            _ userContentController: WKUserContentController,
            didReceive message: WKScriptMessage
        ) {
            guard let text = message.body as? String else { return }
            self.text = text
        }
    }

    @State var text = ""

    var body: some View {
        WebView(
            html: """
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <body>
                    <textarea>\(text)</textarea>
                    <script>
                        const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea')

                        textarea.oninput = () =>
                            webkit.messageHandlers.main.postMessage(textarea.value)
                    </script>
                </body>
            </html>
            """,
            configuration: {
                let userContentController = WKUserContentController()
                userContentController.add(Coordinator(text: $text), name: "main")

                let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
                configuration.userContentController = userContentController

                return configuration
            }()
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend (as I see the simplest in this scenario) to change handling event to

```
textarea.onblur = () =>
    webkit.messageHandlers.main.postMessage(textarea.value)
```

otherwise a complex refactoring is needed to keep away WK* entities from SwiftUI representable wrapper, or changing model to avoid using `@State` or anything resulting in view rebuild, or both of those.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although this doesn't solve my problem, I ended up working around my issue by removing @State and observable objects, making sure there were no view rebuilds on keypress. Fortunately I was able to find a workaround, but I can assume other developers unfortunately won't be able to.